# How to create a non-billing role on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure

I need to create a role on azure which can access everything except billing/usage information.  I've found lots of information on creating a billing-only user and my attempts to inverse the permissions have failed.

My current role definition is:

```
{
    "Name":"Non-billing Owner",
    "IsCustom":true,
    "Description":"Assigns access to all services, etc, except billing access",
    "Actions": [
            "*"
    ],
    "NotActions":[
            "Microsoft.Authorization/*/read",
            "Microsoft.Billing/*"
    ],
    "AssignableScopes":[
            "/subscriptions/4a21****-****-7373",
            "/subscriptions/08be****-****-591b7"
    ]
}
```

Is the only way to achieve what I need is to add each other role to the actions list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code block, at the top, you are giving them everything, and then you are removing certain things. I think, since you are already giving full access, that would, overwrite you trying to take away stuff in the NotActions part.

To get into more detail, * would mean 'Can manage everything, including access'. So, yeah, I think, to get what you want to specifically list each access (and not use *). So, if Azure has 10 things, 8 are stuff you want them to do, and 2 are billing and usage access. You put 8 under Actions. 2 under NonActions.

Comment: you are correct i misunderstood the NotActions not being deny rules in the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-custom-roles#notactions